# How to solve a degenerate system of equations in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have lots of systems of equations, some are underspecified, and I would like to find one non-zero solution if it exists or report that there are none. However, sympy seems to hang trying to find all solutions. Here is an extreme example.

```
from sympy import *
A = Matrix([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
])
syms = symbols("x:12")
s = Matrix(syms)
constraints = [xi**3 - xi for xi in syms]
solve(list(A*s) + constraints, syms)
```

How can I get sympy to just report one non-zero solution quickly in an example like this?   In fact I would be happy if it just reported that there was a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, so I asked on the mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/sympy/PMCYFt4Y6nU

Comment: @asmeurer Thank you. In my case just returning "True" would do too.

Comment: @asmeurer  Can sympy solve equations symbolically as well rather than actually listing all numerical solutions?   In maple for example you would get `solve(0*x=0,x);` 
`x`

Comment: What do you mean symbolically? SymPy *only* does things symbolically. If you want numerical solutions you should use other libraries.

Comment: So you really want to know when a given matrix has a nontrivial solution containing only -1, 0, and 1. You can probably do this way more efficiently. You should ask about it on Math SE.

Comment: I see. you want an unevaluated `Solve` object. SymPy does not have one of those yet. The thing I asked for on the mailing list would be a prerequisite for getting such a thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

Give SymPy increasingly harder systems (with fewer specified 0s) and quit when you get a solution:

```
>>> def nonzsol(eqs, syms):
...     from sympy import subsets
...     for i in range(len(syms)-1,-1,-1):
...         for z in subsets(syms, i):
...             s, nontriv = solve(eqs + list(z), set=True)
...             for v in nontriv:
...                 if any(v):
...                     return dict(zip(s, v))
... 
>>> 
>>> nonzsol(eqs, syms)
{x0: 0, x1: 0, x10: 0, x11: -1, x2: 0, x3: 0, x4: 0, x5: 0, x6: 0, x7: 0, x8: 0, x9: 0}
```